# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component:

Tags: vue.js

I just tried to make a single login form in Vue but it returns

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-text-field

and

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-form

the code in login component:

```js
<template lang="html">
    
  <div>
    <v-form>
      <v-text-field v-model="loginInfo.username" label="Username"/>
      <v-text-field v-model="loginInfo.password" label="Password"/>
      <v-btn>Login</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </div>
    
</template>
    
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return{
        loginInfo: {
           username:'',
           password:'',
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can share the code of where you used this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options to answer the question:

Either you use Vuetify.js as you are trying to in the code provided above. I would recommend checking if you are using Vuetify.js correctly by following [the quick start guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/).

The other option would be not to use Vuetify.js and therefor use the regular HTML expressions in the form:

```html
<div>
    <form>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" v-model="loginInfo.username"/>
      <label for="password">Password</Label>
      <input id="password" type="password" v-model="loginInfo.password"/>
      <input type="submit"value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been great!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and put around 2 hours to figure out. The only problem with me was my browser was getting the cached js file that did not have my required component.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Vite

##### 1. CMD: Install [`vite-plugin-vuetify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-vuetify) plugin

```bash
npm i vite-plugin-vuetify
```

##### 2. Modify [`vite.config.js`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#automatic-treeshaking)

```js
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default {
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vuetify({ autoImport: true }), // Enabled by default
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using Vite

1. create a `vitest.config.ts` file
2. copy the code in your `vite.config.ts`
3. paste it in `vitest.config.ts`
4. add the following to `vue({})` plugin

```
template: {
  compilerOptions: {
    isCustomElement: (tag) => {
       return tag.startsWith('v-') 
    }
  }
}
```

It may look something like so:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => {
            return tag.startsWith('v-')
          }
        }
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

And finally pass `--config` option to CLI, e.g. `vitest --config ./path/to/vitest.config.ts`

Be careful to write the correct path to your `vitest.config.ts` it may probably be `./vitest.config.ts`

If you want to know more [go here](https://vitest.dev/config/#configuration)